# Bool for programmatically changing visibility in NSSecureTextField?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstextfield

What is the bool for toggling visibility/echos bullets on an NS secure text field?

I can do it through the xcode gui but I can't find the bool to do it programmatically.

EDIT - I've found the toggle for echos bullets on the NSSecureTextCell, but it doesn't do what I want. It toggles printing bullets, but doesn't show the text that it hides like I expected, it just stops printing anything at all in the cell. So my question is still open, what is the bool for toggling text visibility in an NSSecureTextField/Cell?

Comment: `isHidden` ?????

Comment: isHidden toggles whether I can see the text field/cell. I want to toggle visibility of the text inside the field, not visibility of the field entirely.

Comment: It's pretty common for password fields to have a little eye symbol next to them to toggle whether you can see what you're typing. I need to know what bool to toggle to implement this.

Comment: It's just the start Apple responds